# Question about foldl function in Racket. (Functional programming)

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, variadic-functions, fold

So I have this line of code:

`(foldl cons '() '(1 2 3 4))`

And the output I get when I run it is this:

`'(4 3 2 1)`

Can you please explain to me why I don’t get `'(1 2 3 4)` instead?

I read the documentation but I am still a bit confused about how `foldl` works. Also if I wanted to define `foldl` how would I specify in Racket that the function can take a variable amount of lists as arguments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. By the definition of left fold, the combining function is called with the *first element* of the list and the *accumulated result so far*, and the result of that call is passed (as the new, updated accumulated result so far) to the recursive invocation of `foldl` with the same combining function and the rest of the list:

```
(foldl  cons                          '()   '(1 2 3))
=
(foldl  cons                  (cons 1 '())    '(2 3))
=
(foldl  cons          (cons 2 (cons 1 '()))     '(3))
=
(foldl  cons  (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 '())))     '())
=
              (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 '())))
```

And when the list is empty, the accumulated result so far is returned as  the final result.

To your second question, variadic functions in Scheme are specified with the dot **`.`** in the argument list, like so:

```
(define (fold-left f acc . lists)
  (if (null? (first lists))            ;; assume all have same length
      acc
      (apply fold-left                 ;; recursive call
             f
             (apply f  (append (map first lists)   ;; combine first elts
                               (list acc)))        ;;  with result so far
             (map rest lists))))       ;; the rests of lists
```

Indeed,

```
(fold-left (lambda (a b result)
             (* result (- a b)))
           1
           '(1 2 3)
           '(4 5 6))
```

returns [`-27`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldl#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29).